# VirtualBox Error Failed to Open Session

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have just installed the new version of VirtualBox 5.1.2 and now i can't start any virtual machine.

I have tried to.

- uninstall VirtualBox
- Installed an order version
- Uninstall then ran Registry Cleaner then install Again.
- Reboot before and after Reinstall

[image: Error Window]

[Link to Log](http://pastebin.com/0cYhbh86)

Update i can only Start the virtual machine in Headless Mode.